# How to remove form after it's submitted in Laravel PHP?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, backend, octobercms

My site uses OctoberCMS and I have a contact form in which I want to display a success message in a partial  and hide the form after it's submitted. Here is the code snippet for the form,I cleared unnecessary parts of it :

```
<form role="form" class="cntct" id="cntct" data-request="onSend" data-request-update="success: '#result'">
     <div class="form-group">
      <!-- Some input fields here !--> 
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Send message</button>
            </div>
          </div>
     </div>
 </form>
 <div id="result">
   {% partial 'success' %}
 </div>
```

Form is working, I can send emails and the `success` partial shows its content without any errors. I just want to remove the form,if it's possible by using PHP, and display only `#result` container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the form partial inside a div with an `id="form"` like this:

```
<div id="form">
    {% partial __SELF__~"::partials/form" %}
</div>
```

then you can hide the the form and show the result from the ajax handler by returning the new partial to be rendered in the div:

```
public function onSend()
{
    # save the data

    return ['#form' => $this-renderPartial('@partials/success')];
}
```

This assumes you have the `form` and `success` partial in your components partials folder.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing is that had to change was   `return ['#form' => $this-renderPartial('@partials/success')]; ` to `return ['#form' => $this->renderPartial('success')];`

Answer (score 0):

just add an flag and check if it is set with @if or @isset.

```
@isset($flag) // or @if
   <form role="form" class="cntct" id="cntct" data-request="onSend" data-request-update="success: '#result'">
     <div class="form-group">
      <!-- Some input fields here !--> 
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Send message</button>
            </div>
          </div>
     </div>
 </form>
@endisset
<div id="result">
   {% partial 'success' %}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An other option is to send the result in the div of the form with ajax
with: **data-request-update="'form-result' : '#yourdiv'"**

```
<div id="contactForm">
<form role="form" data-request="onContactFormSubmit" data-request-update="'form-result' : '#contactForm'" data-request-validate="" _lpchecked="1">
...
</form>
</div>
```

By doing this the form will replaced by your success message. In case of entry error, the form will stay in place.